# Arithmetic Operators in PhP Echo

Tags: php, mysql, math, echo

I currently have the bid price echoing onto the page straight from the database:

```
<?php echo $convert->bid_budget_text; ?>
```

I am trying to multiply the bid price by 25% to include our service fee.
I am new to php and I realize that this is an advanced request. This is my feeble attempt with obvious didn't work and returned a value of 0:

```
<?php echo (($convert->bid_budget_text)+(($convert->bid_budget_text)*25)); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the output of var_dump($convert->bid_budget_text)?

Comment: `$convert->bid_budget_text * 1.25` as long as bid_budget_text is actually numeric?

Comment: unless you're dealing with penny/cents amounts, `*25` would correspond to `2500%`. perhaps you mean `* 0.25`?

Answer (score 1):

Given you got a zero, your `bid_budget_text` is **NOT** a proper number, e.g:

```
php > $price = '$10.00';
php > echo $price + ($price * 25);
0
php > $price = '10.00';
php > echo $price + ($price * 25);
260
```

If php can't convert a string to a number, you get `0` as the result.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code

```
echo (($convert->bid_budget_text)+(($convert->bid_budget_text)*(25/100)));
```

You can change the value 25 to any value.